# Scope of variable declared inside a for loop

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
 int j=0;
}
```

Is j a block variable or a local variable? I see that j's scope is only till the for loop ends

Comment: Is j referred to as a local or a block variable?

Comment: j is a `block variable` which is `local` to the `for loop`, ie the block. So it is `block variable` and `local variable with respect to the loop block`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Local variables are declared in methods, constructors, or blocks.**

From that it's clear that,  **All block variables are local variable's.**

As per definition of [Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

> A block is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed.

So

```
{   //block started

}    //block ended
```

What ever the variables declared inside the block ,the scope restricted to that block.

```
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
 int j=0;
}
```

So `J` scope is restricted to inside that block. That is for loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
 int j=0;
 //do some thing with j ---> compiler says "yes boss"
}
//do some thing with j ---> compiler says "Sorry boss, what is j ??"
```

Comment: Is j referred to as block or local variable?

Comment: Classic definition, `Local variables are declared in methods, constructors, or blocks.`  hope you understand :)

Comment: Sure I do understand! I'v been hearing this couple of times that it is sometimes referred to as a block variable!

Comment: `All block variables are local variable's`. You can refer in both the ways.

Comment: What if the braces of the for loop would be omitted?

Comment: Is `j` in scope for the increment statement? Could I do something like `i += j` instead of `i++`?

Comment: @4castle i += j and i++ are tow different things

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yes, but is the scope of the increment statement actually broader than the curly brackets, if `i` is visible but `j` is not?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I made a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37892846/5743988) about it now. Feel free to answer there if you have something to add.

Comment: `i` apparently persists after the loop is finished, so apparently the counter exists in the scope of the counter that contains it (which confuses me)

Answer (score 2):

It is a local variable to that for block.  Outside of that for loop, j will cease to exist.

Answer (score 1):

j variable is accessible inside {this block} only. That not only means that it can't be changed anywhere else, but also it is recreated every time loop loops.

Answer (score 1):

The word "local" means that something is available somewhere, but not outside the bounds of this "somewhere". In Java variables declared inside a block have a [block scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope), which means that they're available only inside this block - they're **local** to it.

Answer (score 0):

j has scope in the loop only, outside the loop, j can not be accessed.
For more on scopes, [refer the link, it will be helpful.](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)