# "Cannot resolve symbol" of my declared variable?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

The solution to my problem is probably something really obvious, but I have yet to find it. If you're at all wondering what this code is suppose to do, it's suppose to take 10 user-inputted numbers, add them together, and output the average. My only error thus far is that where I have `double average = sum / 10;`
it doesn't read the variable `sum` and I'm at a total loss as to why.

```
import java.io.*;
class Average
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        // declare some variables
        int count = 0;
        String inInput;


        // declare array constructer
        double[] userInput = new double[9];

        // declare a reader
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inStream);


        // print out the array
        while (count >= 9)
        {
            if (count != 10)
            { 
                System.out.println ("Please enter a value");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println ("Please enter another value");
            }
            inInput = reader.readLine();
            double inInputDouble = Double.parseDouble(inInput);
            userInput[count] = inInputDouble;
            double sum = sum + userInput[count];
            count++;
        }
        double average = sum / 10;
        System.out.println ("The average of all the numbers you have entered is" + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do ``double sum = sum + userInput[count];`` for the first time, the computer doesn't know where that ``sum`` you're trying to use in an addition comes from.

Comment: You are using sum outside the while loop that it was declared in. It is outside the scope of your declaration.

Comment: this code is a wreck :)) , in the future... do things stept by step, iterativ, so you can actually debug your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable can only be used inside the scope of which it is declared. Your `sum` variable is declared inside the `while` body and can thus only be used inside that scope.

Move the declaration of `sum` outside of the while loop as follows:

```
double sum = 0;

// print out the array
while (count >= 9)
{
    ...
    sum = sum + userInput[count];
    ...
}

...
```

You probably also want to change `count >= 9` to `count < 9` to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, the sum must be declared befor the for loop.
Scopes are like brackets in programs,

```
int a ..
{
   int b ...
   {
       int c ...
   }
}
```

if the instruction evaluated is on  line with `a`, it cannot know about the state of `b` and `c`, since they are not declared yet.

if instuction pointer evaluates line  with int `c` , it know about all the variables because it allready got into the 3rd level of scoping. but since  `c` is declared on 3rd level, after  the instuction pointer goes outer from the brackets, if you did not saved the  value of `c` in an upper leveled variable, the value gets lost, since `c` gets  cleaned, and it is not accessible(outer scope). It is the same like you would want to read a variable from another file... you cant, scopes  are like sticky notes which start from outer and append new smaller stickynotes, which after iot has been worked with , they get removed

```
scope:  class definitions >   method definitions         >       block definitions(for, while, if)
      visible everywhere  -   visible under the method    >   visible in the block only  
                              after it exits method all          (eg: for (int i;..)
                              is gone                            i is not visible outer the  for                       /                                                                     brackets
```

another bug:

`new double[9];` ? 
you said it is supposed to take 10 ints... 
at initialistion you dont count 0... 0 is used at 0 based indexing (`a[0],a[1],a[2]` needs a `new int[3]`)... set it to new double[10];

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Fixed, added an explanation also.

Answer (score 0):

int count is always 0, so it never goes into while(count >= 9) and when sum is called it won't be defined at all, change it for while(count <= 9)

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring you variable `sum` inside the `while` loop block. Once that block finishes the variable goes out of scope and is no longer defined.

Put your `double sum` declaration before the `while` and you should be fine.

Comment: I tried that at one point too, and then it wouldn't read it in the `while` loop.

Edit; Just tried it again for the fun of it, and it didn't even fix the first error, only made them both state the variable was uninitialized.

Comment: This is because you got the loop condition wrong. See the last point of by answer.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of sum is the block it's declared in which is the block of the while loop.
Declare sum outside the while loop.

It doesn't make too much sense to redeclare this variable over and over again, because you want to sum up all numbers.

Take a look at this question:
[Scope of variable declared inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463138/scope-of-variable-declared-inside-a-for-loop)