# Can I use the loop iterator outside the for statement?

Tags: java, loops, variable-assignment

So I have a variable `lopvr` that I declared inside what I am going to call the "for statement". This is what I am referring to:

```
for (int lopvr=1;lopvr==1;);
```

I would like to know if I can use the variable outside the "for statement", like this:

```
    for (int lopvr=1;lopvr==1;);
    {
      System.out.println("Enter the passcode:");
      Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    codeEntered= sc.nextInt();
    int passcode = 1409, attempts = 4;
    
    if (passcode == codeEntered) {
      System.out.println("Correct");
    //other code
      lopvr=0;
       }
    else{//other code
    }
```

For clarification, I am trying to change `lopvr`, which was declared INSIDE the "for statement", to set the value to 0, OUTSIDE the "for statement", to end the loop when the right conditions are met (You get the passcode right)

Comment: `for (int lopvr=1;lopvr==1;);` <- is this last semicolon intentional? Do you know what that will do?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463138/scope-of-variable-declared-inside-a-for-loop

Comment: The short answer is that you can use `lopvr` in the body of the for loop. Usually this body is inside `{}` after the line you are calling the "for statement" and is technically part of the for statement. However, you have an extra `;` on the first line of the for loop that terminates the statement prematurely. See the links at the top of this page for some examples and explanations.

Comment: Side note: TrY IMPLEMenting the same logic with a `while` loop and compare the two. Which do you like better?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you for noticing the semicolon. I am mostly new to programming and put that there not thinking about the brackets after. I will test your answer and be back in a minute or two. Edit: This worked exactly the way I wanted it to. Thanks! (I like `for` loops better for now)